# Long to wide df format in R - complicated column headers

Tags: r

I am currently working with sleep tracking data in R, and the data output shows a bunch of sleep variables for each day of the week. This basically means I have multiple sets of data for a single person, and I want to merge it so each subject ID is only listed once.

I am merging my dataset with someone else's, and I need to match their formatting. My file output currently looks something like this:

| PID | Day.of.the.Week | Date | Time.in.Bed | Total.Sleep.Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 8008 | Wednesday | 05/12/2018 | 06:00:00 | 06:00:00 |
| 8009 | Wednesday | 05/12/2018 | 06:00:00 | 06:00:00 |
| 8010 | Wednesday | 05/12/2018 | 06:00:00 | 06:00:00 |
| 8008 | Tuesday | 04/12/2018 | 08:06:00 | 08:06:00 |
| 8009 | Tuesday | 04/12/2018 | 08:06:00 | 08:06:00 |
| 8010 | Tuesday | 04/12/2018 | 08:06:00 | 08:06:00 |
| 8008 | Thursday | 06/12/2018 | 04:49:00 | 04:49:00 |
| 8009 | Thursday | 06/12/2018 | 04:49:00 | 04:49:00 |
| 8010 | Thursday | 06/12/2018 | 04:49:00 | 04:49:00 |
| 8008 | Sunday | 09/12/2018 | 08:09:00 | 08:09:00 |
| 8009 | Sunday | 09/12/2018 | 08:09:00 | 08:09:00 |

However I want to make it into a wide format, where each column is day of the week_total.sleep time, like this:

| PID | Monday.total.sleep.time | Tuesday.total.sleep.time | etc | Monday.number.of.sleep.episodes | Tuesday.number.of.sleep.episodes | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8008 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8009 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8010 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I wouldn't personally organise my data like this which is why I'm a bit stuck, I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: How is `number.of.sleep.episodes` variable calculated? based on the first data set.

Comment: It is possible to count the number of days per `PID` that a sleep episode has been recorded and use it for that column, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is somehow close to your desired output. If that's the case I can make further modifications:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Day.of.the.Week, values_from = c("Time.in.Bed", 
                                                            "Total.Sleep.Time")) %>%
  group_by(PID) %>%
  summarise(across(-c(1, 2), ~ first(na.omit(.x))))


# A tibble: 3 x 8
    PID Time.in.Bed_Tues~ Time.in.Bed_Thur~ Time.in.Bed_Sund~ Total.Sleep.Time~ Total.Sleep.Time~
  <int> <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>            
1  8008 08:06:00          04:49:00          08:09:00          06:00:00          08:06:00         
2  8009 08:06:00          04:49:00          08:09:00          06:00:00          08:06:00         
3  8010 08:06:00          04:49:00          NA                06:00:00          08:06:00         
# ... with 2 more variables: Total.Sleep.Time_Thursday <chr>, Total.Sleep.Time_Sunday <chr>
```

Based on the assumption that the `number.of.sleep.episode` is the count of `Day.Of.The.Week` per `PID` the following can also be true:

```
df %>%
  group_by(PID, Day.of.the.Week) %>%
  add_count(name = "number.of.sleep.episode") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Day.of.the.Week, values_from = c("Time.in.Bed", 
                                                            "number.of.sleep.episode")) %>%
  group_by(PID) %>%
  summarise(across(-c(1, 2), ~ first(na.omit(.x))))


# A tibble: 3 x 9
    PID Time.in.Bed_Wedn~ Time.in.Bed_Tues~ Time.in.Bed_Thur~ Time.in.Bed_Sun~ number.of.sleep.e~
  <int> <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>                         <int>
1  8008 06:00:00          08:06:00          04:49:00          08:09:00                          1
2  8009 06:00:00          08:06:00          04:49:00          08:09:00                          1
3  8010 06:00:00          08:06:00          04:49:00          NA                                1
# ... with 3 more variables: number.of.sleep.episode_Tuesday <int>,
#   number.of.sleep.episode_Thursday <int>, number.of.sleep.episode_Sunday <int>
```